# setPropertyActionListener with h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using a datatable with two columns which will have a label and a selectOneMenu.

I need to display the selectOneMenu list dynamically, for which i need to set the level id here in the bean.
In commandbutton/commandLink , we have the option for setting the value with the help of f:setPropertyActionListener.
I am just wondering how to set the value while I am using selectonemenu.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <p:dataTable style="width:750px;" id="inResultTable" var="result"
    value="#{RequestBean.independentFields}">
    <p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value=" " />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{result.field_label}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="" />
     </f:facet>
    <ui:repeat value="#{RequestBean.independentFields}" var="itm">   
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{RequestBean.field1Value}"
     rendered="#{result.level_id==itm.level_id}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{RequestBean.indField}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{RequestBean.level_id}"
     value="#{itm.level_id}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
     </ui:repeat>
     </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the change ajax event.

When some item will be change in your selectOneMenu the ajax call some method in you Bean.

Like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{RequestBean.field1Value}"
     rendered="#{result.level_id==itm.level_id}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{RequestBean.indField}" />
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{yourBean.yourMethodToChangeSomeValue}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and in your method you can use the value of fieldValue or pass with parameter to another Bean method in you xhtml.